# Stop the Image Scrolling when it reached Nav bar CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to figure out how to stop the image from moving/scrolling up before it reached the nav bar using javascript and css. but it still can scroll down.

I will really appreciate any help in advance thank you.
I attached the image of the desire output

[image: output desire]

My code is below

https://codesandbox.io/s/html-css-navbar-forked-06mjm0?file=/src/styles.css

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Navigation Bar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="#">Brand name</a>
      </div>
      <div class="menuIcon">
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="line"></div>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav-links">
        <li class="nav-item active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="mainSec">
      <div id="animatedDiv"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
    var aDiv = document.getElementById("animatedDiv");

function changeWidth() {
  var scrollVal = window.pageYOffset;

  //Changing CSS Width

  /* This lags if you scroll fast.. aDiv.style.width = (100 - (scrollVal*100/800)) + "%"; 
  I just tried it out, so instead use the code down above, 800 to 1500 doesn't matter, I just increased time of animation
*/
  //NOTE this line checks if PERCENT <= 10 then sets width to 10%
  50 - (scrollVal * 100) / 1500 <= 10
    ? (aDiv.style.width = "10%")
    : (aDiv.style.width = 50 - (scrollVal * 100) / 1500 + "%");
}

window.addEventListener(
  "scroll",
  function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(changeWidth);
  },
  false
);

const menuIcon = document.querySelector(".menuIcon");
const menuIcons = document.querySelectorAll(".menuIcon .line");
const navLinks = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links li");
const logo = document.querySelector(".logo");
menuIcon.addEventListener("click", () => {
  navLinks.classList.toggle("open");
  logo.classList.toggle("close");
  items.forEach((item) => {
    item.classList.toggle("fade");
  });
  menuIcons.forEach((Icon) => {
    Icon.classList.toggle("open");
  });
});

const menu = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
const menuItems = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links li");

menuItems.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", function () {
    menu.querySelector(".active").classList.remove("active");
    item.classList.add("active");
  });
});
```

style.css

```
   .mainSec {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
#animatedDiv {
  background: url("https://media.tenor.com/images/34b16b199449136a845ea0300ff2cef3/raw")
    no-repeat;

  min-height: 200vh;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 20%;
}
#secondPage {
  background: url("https://www.downloadclipart.net/large/doraemon-png-free-download.png")
    no-repeat;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: rgb(12, 77, 151);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

nav .logo a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px 10px;
}
nav .nav-links {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.nav-links li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-links .active {
  background-color: black;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
nav .nav-links li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  nav {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
  }
  .logo {
    height: 10vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .logo a {
    text-align: center;
  }
  nav .menuIcon {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 30%;
    right: 5%;
  }
  nav .menuIcon .line {
    width: 30px;
    margin: 5px 0px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
  }
  nav .menuIcon .line:nth-child(1).open {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    width: 40px;
    height: 5px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 16px;
    transition: all 1s ease;
  }
  nav .menuIcon .line:nth-child(2).open {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  nav .menuIcon .line:nth-child(3).open {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    width: 40px;
    height: 5px;
    transition: all 1s ease;
  }
  nav .nav-links {
    margin-top: -10px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(12, 77, 151);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    clip-path: circle(50px at 90% -10%);
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(50px at 90% -10%);
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
  }
  .nav-links li {
    margin: 40px 0px;
  }
  nav .nav-links.open {
    clip-path: circle(1000px at 90% -10%);
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(1000px at 90% -10%);
  }
  .nav-links li {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .nav-links li a {
    font-size: 25px;
  }
  .nav-links li:nth-child(1) {
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0.2s;
  }
  .nav-links li:nth-child(2) {
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0.4s;
  }
  .nav-links li:nth-child(3) {
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0.6s;
  }
  .nav-links li:nth-child(4) {
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0.8s;
  }
  li.fade {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .logo.close {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Min Height of #animatedDiv should be set to 87vh instead of 200vh** it worked for me. No need to change the JS. See output:
[visit](https://umllx3.csb.app/)
[image]

```js
var aDiv = document.getElementById("animatedDiv");

function changeWidth() {
  var scrollVal = window.pageYOffset;

  //Changing CSS Width

  /* This lags if you scroll fast.. aDiv.style.width = (100 - (scrollVal*100/800)) + "%"; 
  I just tried it out, so instead use the code down above, 800 to 1500 doesn't matter, I just increased time of animation
*/
  //NOTE this line checks if PERCENT <= 10 then sets width to 10%
  50 - (scrollVal * 100) / 1500 <= 10 ?
    (aDiv.style.width = "10%") :
    (aDiv.style.width = 50 - (scrollVal * 100) / 1500 + "%");
}

window.addEventListener(
  "scroll",
  function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(changeWidth);
  },
  false
);

const menuIcon = document.querySelector(".menuIcon");
const menuIcons = document.querySelectorAll(".menuIcon .line");
const navLinks = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links li");
const logo = document.querySelector(".logo");
menuIcon.addEventListener("click", () => {
  navLinks.classList.toggle("open");
  logo.classList.toggle("close");
  items.forEach((item) => {
    item.classList.toggle("fade");
  });
  menuIcons.forEach((Icon) => {
    Icon.classList.toggle("open");
  });
});

const menu = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
const menuItems = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links li");

menuItems.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", function() {
    menu.querySelector(".active").classList.remove("active");
    item.classList.add("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.mainSec {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#animatedDiv {
  background: url("https://media.tenor.com/images/34b16b199449136a845ea0300ff2cef3/raw") no-repeat;
  display: block;
  min-height: 87vh;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 25%;
  z-index: 4;
}

#secondPage {
  background: url("https://www.downloadclipart.net/large/doraemon-png-free-download.png") no-repeat;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: rgb(12, 77, 151);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 6;
}

nav .logo a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px 10px;
}

nav .nav-links {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.nav-links li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-links .active {
  background-color: black;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

nav .nav-links li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}


/*responsive*/

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  nav {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
  }
  .logo {
    height: 10vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .logo a {
    text-align: center;
  }
  nav .menuIcon {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 30%;
    right: 5%;
  }
  nav .menuIcon .line {
    width: 30px;
    margin: 5px 0px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
  }
  nav .menuIcon .line:nth-child(1).open {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    width: 40px;
    height: 5px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 16px;
    transition: all 1s ease;
  }
  nav .menuIcon .line:nth-child(2).open {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  nav .menuIcon .line:nth-child(3).open {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    width: 40px;
    height: 5px;
    transition: all 1s ease;
  }
  nav .nav-links {
    margin-top: -10px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(12, 77, 151);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    clip-path: circle(50px at 90% -10%);
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(50px at 90% -10%);
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
  }
  .nav-links li {
    margin: 40px 0px;
  }
  nav .nav-links.open {
    clip-path: circle(1000px at 90% -10%);
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(1000px at 90% -10%);
  }
  .nav-links li {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .nav-links li a {
    font-size: 25px;
  }
  .nav-links li:nth-child(1) {
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0.2s;
  }
  .nav-links li:nth-child(2) {
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0.4s;
  }
  .nav-links li:nth-child(3) {
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0.6s;
  }
  .nav-links li:nth-child(4) {
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0.8s;
  }
  li.fade {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .logo.close {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Navigation Bar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#">Brand name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menuIcon">
      <div class="line"></div>
      <div class="line"></div>
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li class="nav-item active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div class="mainSec">
    <div id="animatedDiv"></div>
  </div>

  <script src="src/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

It would be best if you changed the CSS for responsiveness.